# androidで画面遷移時に押されたボタンを特定する方法

Tags: android, java, kotlin

androidでIntentを利用して画面遷移することを考えています。子画面で画面を閉じるときに親画面に子画面の選択内容を反映したいのですが、画面遷移時に親画面で押されたitemが何かを特定または記憶しておく方法は無いでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`と`onActivityResult(Intent, CharSequence)`でできると思います．どうでしょうか？

Answer (score -1):

複数の設定状態取得が必要なら、Applicationクラスを継承したクラスを生成して、
どの画面からでも参照可能な大域変数として扱うと簡単に実装できます。
もしくはサービスを生成してバックグラウンドで走らせておいて、
画面が消えるタイミングで設定を記憶させておく方法もあります。

子のアクティビティから再びIntentを使用して画面遷移するのであれば親を呼び出す際に、

```
Intent intent = = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),xxxx.class);
boolean 
intent.putExtra("VALUE1", value1);
intent.putExtra("VALUE2", value2);
startActivity(i);
```

上記の様に起動する画面に引数として渡すのもアリかと思います。
起動する側はonCreateかonResumeでgetExtraで取得します。
引数として受け渡す型は整数でも文字列でも可能です。